# How to directly export a collection of DTOs to CSV, Excel or PDF?

Tags: excel, jsf, jsf-2, export, primefaces

I have a `List<MyDto>` which I want to export with PrimeFaces. I tried with `<p:dataExporter>`, but it seems that it only uses UI `<p:dataTable>` content.

How can I directly export a list of DTOs to CSV, Excel or PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a library to handle this. Primefaces doesn't inherently know how to display your data (it analyzes the columns and then exports based on that) so you need to give it some hints. The short answer is that you can easily create a table either programatically via reflection on the DTO and binding it to the page or by creating a simple data-table and set it to a style of "display:none" and then using the exporter.

Alternatively you can look at a reporting suite like JasperReports that handles "printing" to the above formats, but again, you will need to do something to interpret it. If you don't care about performance JSON-Lib has a very nice "toXML" method that will rip down a DTO to xml which could then be easily exported to any of the formats you choose.

Basically, you're looking at ~ 1 hour of work if it is a complex set of DTOs or 10 minutes if it isn't--as long as bandwidth isn't an issue this should be completely painless.